# BottomAppBar item on right side

Tags: android, android-bottomappbar

I would like to use a `BottomAppBar` with a `FAB` in center mode.
i have 4 item to show and want to split like

[image: this one]

Is that possible ? if so : how ?

EDIT: I found the solution here : [How to make Bottom AppBar like Google Home App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810905/how-to-make-bottom-appbar-like-google-home-app)

Comment: Its simple just use **`app:fabAlignmentMode="center"`** in your `BottomAppBar`

Comment: Please share code snippets with us what you have tried so far as well as the other research that you have done. Include what the result is as well. Before asking for the answer, it would be nice to see that you put some effort into it.

Comment: I've tries to add "space/blank item" but that doesn't work properly. See screenshot here : http://prntscr.com/lc7sip

Comment: Post your xml for the bottombar as part of the question and we can have  a look at it

Comment: Hi. I found the solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810905/how-to-make-bottom-appbar-like-google-home-app Just need fews changes for the ripple effect and here we go

Answer (score -1):

you need to add bottombar with fab as below in your xml

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
      android:id="@+id/bar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
      app:fabAttached="true"
      app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_24"/>

  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"/>
```

also check [this tutorial](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708) if you want to know how to setup your bottomappbar

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake. I don't have problem to set the fab in center mode. The issue is how to set two icon on the left side and two icon on the right side